# Remove Specific value From Firebase Database

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I want to Delete Specific value from Firebase Database following is Database which i have stored**

[image]

**Now, I want to Delete** Following Values

`fname: "John"`

`lname: "wick"`

[image]

`Here, What i have try to delete specific value from Firebase..`

```
DatabaseReference demo = mReference.child("demo").orderByValue().equalTo("John").getRef();

    demo.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But this will delete all values from database...

`Question` : **How to delete that specific value??? what i have to do for that**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`try using `addChildEventListener` as below,

```
Query queryRef = mReference.child("demo").orderByChild("fname").equalTo("John");

queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
      snapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,,.. but Nothing happen!

Comment: @UttamPanchasara please check my answer now I updated!

Comment: Thank you... Your solution work like charm also check my answer which is also work with me.

Answer (score 1):

hi try using this code,

```
    mReference.child("demo").orderByChild("fname").equalTo("John").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mReference.child("demo").child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).setValue(null);
        }

       @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Log.w("TodoApp", "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
         }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. for your response I have found answer with some modification in your answer. see my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
mReference.child("demo").orderByChild("fname").equalTo("John").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
            }


           @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                  Log.w("TodoApp", "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
             }
   });
```

Comment: Already try this, not working... `dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();` and `dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);` both are same thing.. read firebase doc.. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#delete_data

Comment: Do you try : `mReference.child("demo").orderByChild("fname").equalTo("John")`

Answer (score 0):

Well Thanks to all, After Modification with lots of answer and query.. This is what worked with me.

```
mReference.child("demo").orderByChild("fname").equalTo("John").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            mReference.child("demo").child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).setValue(null);

            //also work
            //dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);  
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hopefully this will help you
Thanks

```
database.getReference().child("Groups").child(groupItem.getGroupkey()).child("members").child(groupMember.getKey()).removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                       new CustomMessage(GroupDetailsActivity.this, "Successfully deleted");
                                   }
                               }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                       Customlog.showlogD("ERROR_MSG",e.getMessage());
                                   }
                               });
```

Database structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw3Ia.png