# How do I filter data and return only the relevant users?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, tableview

I have a tableView in my application that returns all of the users inside of my users node in my Firebase Database. I have a picture of my database tree below, along with the relevant code. How do I get the tableView to return only the users with the numberId set to 1. As I only have 2 users in my database, I want it to return that one user and not the user with the numberId set to 2. At the moment, it returns all of the users. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

[image]

```
class User: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var numberId: String?
    var password: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
}

class UsersController: UITableViewController {

    let cellId = "cellId"
    var users = [User]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

        tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        fetchUser()
    }

    func fetchUser() {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User()

                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

                self.users.append(user)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    func handleCancel() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell

        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        cell .detailTextLabel?.text = user.email

        if let profileImageUrl = user.profileImageUrl {

            cell.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCachWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrl)
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 56
    }
}

class UserCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 58, y: (textLabel?.frame.origin.y)! - 2, width: (textLabel?.frame.width)!, height: (textLabel?.frame.height)!)

        detailTextLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 58, y: (detailTextLabel?.frame.origin.y)! + 2, width: (detailTextLabel?.frame.width)!, height: (detailTextLabel?.frame.height)!)
    }

    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.layer.masksToBounds = true
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupProfileImageView()
    }

    func setupProfileImageView() {
        addSubview(profileImageView)

        profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `queryOrderedByChild` and `queryEqualToValue`.

```
func fetchUser() {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrderedByChild("numberId").queryEqualToValue(1).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User()

            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

            self.users.append(user)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In Swift 3 the line would be FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "numberId").queryEqual(toValue: 1).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

Answer (score 0):

You can have idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657449/remove-specific-value-from-firebase-database),  I don't know about swift how to write code in but.. you can have idea and hope you can write code like wise.

Comment: The question is tagged for Swift.

Comment: Please don't add answers when you're not familiar with the language. This helps to keep SO clean and makes it easier for people to find the correct answers. Thanks!