# How to pull specific value from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on the app where I need to pull specific value from the firebase. For this case I need to pull "Score" where "uID" equals current User id. What would be a best way to do so.

Thank you for any help.

[image]

Comment: Instead of having **Leaders->key->data** make it **Leaders->user id-> key->data** then you can simply fetch the data for a user you want

Comment: Maybe you have some sample code? that would be a great help

Comment: It is very easy, just follow firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) and you will get it right. Make sure you have a proper db construction the one I mentioned before

Comment: you can refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657449/remove-specific-value-from-firebase-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase will always return full nodes. So you cannot just return the score for a user. But you *can* return the common node that both the score and user are under (the one starting with `-K...`) by using a Firebase query:

```
DatabaseReference leadersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Leaders");
Query query = leadersRef.orderByChild("uID").equalTo("vUdnKx...");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getKey()+": "+child.child("Score").getValue(Long.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
})
```

Note that the code loops over the `snapshot` in the result. That is because a query will potentially have multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

For more reading see the [Firebase documentation on handling lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) and [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Thanks...it seems I got desired result

Comment: Regarding the multiple results, each user will have only one leader "child" so it should cause any major problem