# Remove a specific value from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already followed  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657449/remove-specific-value-from-firebase-database). But unfortunately, when I delete a data with the SAME value as the other, it gets deleted as well. I want to be deleting a single data only.

Here is my database structure. [image: Here is my database].

I want to be only deleting only a single value.

```
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("address").equalTo(tvPatientAddress.getText().toString());

                        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
```

I have this code

**Any chance you guys have an idea? I think the best way to do this is by getting the ID of the patient and deleting that data, since the ID is unique. Any help appreciated!**

Comment: You can give an example which node you want to delete in given picture ?

Comment: For example I want to delete, Dummy1 @BurhanuddinRashid

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, get the specific value that you want to delete, then remove it.

If you do not know about the key of that object, you have to query to get the object key from `DataSnapshot.` This can be done by using `getKey() method` (ex. `postsnapshot.getKey()`)

Or, check out my [Firebase Helper Classes](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Clean-architecture-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/droid/clean_architecture_android_tutorial/network/firebase)  or [Firebase Helper Class Tutorial](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper.git)

```
mdatabaseReference.child("users").orderByKey().equalTo(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

    String key = postsnapshot.getKey();
    dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();

 }
```

Comment: How will I be getting the UID?

Comment: private String uId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

Comment: String key = postsnapshot.getKey();use this and  get key of object @KyleAnthonyDizon

Comment: I'll try this mate

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Dummy1 by following code :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dentist-ass-key")
.child("Patients")
.child("91C...key")
.child("-KwYUqs...key")
.child("firstname")
.removeValue();
```

I have given the example to show how you need to tranverse a tree to delete a node "Dummy1" username

If you don't know the key of the items to remove, you will first need to query the database to determine those keys:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dentist-ass-key");
Query dummyQuery = ref
    .child("Patients")
    .child("91C...key")
    .orderByChild("firstname")
    .equalTo("Dummy1");

dummyQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dummySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            dummySnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: How will I get this key? .child("-KwYUqs...key")

Comment: But I have 2 data with the same "firstname" of "Dummy1", they'll both get deleted?

Comment: Yes..it will delete both because you are querying for Dummy1 username

Comment: But it will delete in only "91C...key" node

Comment: Yes, but those are lists of patients, I want to be deleting only one specific child

Comment: You need to specify some other attributes too else how will you differentiate between to two `Dummy1` patients name

Answer (score 0):

Your filter query is wrong ... 
and to delete Patients/nodeid/patient_id/address set to null