# Firebase - Delete specific value without parent key

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I am attempting to delete a value from a node in Firebase. 
It seems that the onDataChange is not being reached.

I tried looking up the docs and articles and used some of the code that I saw referenced in multiple places(e.g. [Remove Specific value From Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657449/remove-specific-value-from-firebase-database)). Log statements inside onDataChange are not being called but the Log statements before it are. The scope of email is fine as can be seen by the log statement

```
I/emailRemove: 111@aol.com
I/removeEmail: Inside Method
```

In this example I would like to delete whatever area has the email "111@aol.com" :
[image: Delete Email]

```
private void removeEmail() {
        Log.i("emailRemove", email);
        Log.i("removeEmail","Inside Method");

        Query emailQuery = mDatabase.child("emailAddress").equalTo(email);

        emailQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot emailSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i("snapshot", emailSnapshot.toString());
                    Log.i("snapshotRef", emailSnapshot.getRef().toString());
                    emailSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to filter by a child property, you should use `orderByChild(...)`:

```
Query emailQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("emailAddress").equalTo(email);

emailQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```

You'll also want to make sure you run this query against `RC9...`, since that is the only node where the child nodes have an `emailAddress` property.

Comment: Hi Frank. orderByChild is one of the methods/implementations I tried but did not reach the onDataChange. Also to clarify, RC9 is just one of the Admins who has added people into Unverified Employees node, so in the long run there will be many more UID's than RC9 that have emails under them

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that first sentence. But to query the structure you've shown, you must use `orderByChild()` and run it on a specific node as I've shown. If you call another `orderBy...` method or run it on a different level in the tree, it won't work.

Comment: What I meant by that was I had ran the code you showed above in a previous implementation and got the same result ( it didn't work )